# Does Date() always init UTC date?

Tags: swift

I'd like to know if  Date() always init UTC date.

Example:

App is running in location UTC-8

Call Date() => date in UTC or UTC-8?

Thanks.

Comment: `Date()` inits a current point in time. It's completely independent of any timezome.

Comment: Right at the tops of [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate): "NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001)." `(NS)Date)` just happen to have an implementation of `CustomStringConvertible` that doesn't show you this underlying `Double` number of seconds since the reference date, but instead formats the time using UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date() initiates a single point in time, independent of any particular calendar system or time zone. Date values represent a time interval relative to an absolute reference date.

So the displayed value will be different depending on timezone, e.g.

`01/01/2020T00:00:00` in UTC

will be presented as

`31/12/2019T23:00:00` in UTC+1

Comment: Still dont understand that. I have date for example "20.03.2020 19:00" (UTC+1) as a string. I wanna call Date() and get actual date in UTC+1 (not local date). How to do this?

Comment: even though it store in UTC time, it should show correct Date and Time in your currently set timezone. Apple doesn't advise you to manipulate it as timezones are quite complicated. If something isn't working as you would expect try to provide some example an I will try to help you

Comment: So if I have Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Prague")!.secondsFromGMT())) it will always give me time in Prague? No matter if am I in USA or Russia?

Comment: theoretically yes, but with this approach you wil have an Hour in gmt + 1 hour, its still standard Date UTC that swift can automatically format when displaying basing on your actuall timezone, with your function `let d = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Prague")!.secondsFromGMT()))' If you will `print(d)` it will print 2020-03-20 09:20:36 +0000, but when `print(d.string())` it will print 20/03/2020 10:20. 
Dates are really tricky

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for! I dont care much about d.string(). I only need that Date() as UTC date no matter where am I (USA/Russia). Thanks for help!